# update don't work in Django

Tags: django, sql-update

I am reading the data from a worksheet and trying to update a table.

```
...
try:
    equipment = Equipment.objects.filter(location=0,  branch=branch).update(
        has_microphone = has_microphone,
        has_horn = has_horn,
        has_camera = has_camera,
       door_amount = door_to_str)          
    equipment.save()

except Exception as e:
    print e
```

Error in console:
'int' object has no attribute 'save'

Somebody can help me please?

Comment: Don't call save. Update does the update directly in the db abs doesn't return a model instance.

Comment: Also, don't ever catch all exceptions like that.